# intuition about change of variables, "speed"' of integration.

Tags: calculus

Start with the general change of variables law,
$$
   \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(g(x)) \cdot g'(x) dx
$$
and consider the particular case is $f(x)=1$, $g(x)=3x$ 
$$
   \int_{3a}^{3b} 1 dx = \int_a^b 1 \cdot 3 dx
$$
(if this is correct - no doubt there is a stupid error somewhere in this post).

Instead consider the alternate (incorrect) equation
$$
   \int_{3a}^{3b} f(x) dx = \int_a^b f(3x) dx
$$
which might look reasonable to a beginner, at least if you think of only the case $f(x)=1$.
But of course putting $f(x)=1$ gives
$$
   \int_{3a}^{3b} 1 dx = \int_a^b 1 dx
$$
which is wrong.

*The question:*  Focus on the "might look reasonable to a beginner". Is it reasonable as an intuition to say that traversing
the same interval at 3x the "speed" gives 1/3 of the integral mass.

If this were a discrete situation of sampling a from a row of beads once per unit time, then if the sampling mechanism goes over the row faster, less beads will be gathered, so the intuition works.

Edit: I think the question is stupid. It is trying to develop an intuition starting from an equation that is incorrect. Using the correct equation and the interpretation "area under the curve" works, no need for this question.

Answer (score 3):

While technically okay to use the same token, to spare confusion it is best practice to change the variable token when changing the variable.

$$\begin{align}\int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(x)\operatorname dx ~&=~ \int_a^b f(g(u))~g'(u)\operatorname d u \\ \int_{3a}^{3b} f(x)\operatorname d x ~&=~ \int_a^b f(3u)\cdot 3\operatorname d u \\ &=~ \int_a^b 1\cdot 3\operatorname d u \end{align}$$

> *The question:* is it reasonable as an intuition to say that traversing the same interval at $3\times$ the "speed" gives $1/3$ of the integral mass.

The usual interpretation is that an interval of $1/3$ size with $3\times$ the *density* -but the same shape- has *the same mass*.

$~$

---

(Note: That is for linear transformations.   The basic principle applies for nonlinear $g()$, but it is a bit obscured.)

Comment: Thank you.  Can you clarify though?  I haven't seen the "density" of a function mentioned anywhere. Usually it is presented that integral = area under a curve, that's all, not that the area has some additional density to it.  I also have not seen my interpretation of "speed" mentioned.

Comment: Keywords: "probability mass function" and "probability density function".